# FB.logout() called without an access token. javascript sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Totally lost on this and [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) don't really give any insight on this...

Using the Facebook Javascript SDK in my app with this login button code:

```
<fb:login-button scope="manage_pages,read_insights,ads_management" autologoutlink="true" size="large"></fb:login-button>
```

As per the docs, `autologoutlink=true` param turns the `login` button to `log out` once the user is logged in. **I want to keep this functionality and not write my own button code**

This event calls `FB.logout` but still returns the error message in the callback

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {                                              
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        // FB.logout() called without an access token.
    });
});
```

I would like to use the Facebook Login Widget and not my own button for login, so the other answers on the same subject don't help. I don't understand how I'm supposed to pass the access_token to prove I'm authorized to logout...

Comment: I’m pretty sure the logput button handles logging the user out on its own, so there is no need for you to call `FB.logout`. Actually I think `auth.logout` fires when the user has already logged out – and that would explain why you don’t have a valid access token any more when you call the method. Just don’t call it at all, and let the button handle logout.

Comment: You are correct in that it logs the logged in user out of facebook but not out of the site as the access_token was stored in a cookie. I wanted to call FB.logout to clear the access_token. This was confirmed when I logged into an account, pulled Graph data, logged out, logged in as another user and it was still using the previous access_token and returning the original users Graph API data.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible, at least in no way I can figure out. Quick solution is call this function from a custom `Log Out` button:

```
function fbLogoutUser() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                document.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The page reload makes another request to Facebook which then sees the unauthorized state and removes the cookie from the browser which in turn invalidates the access_token. So this logs out the user from the site and from Facebook.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function fbLogoutUser() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response && response.status === 'connected') {

        FB.logout(function(response) {
            document.location.reload();
        });
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
             FB.logout(function(response) {
            document.location.reload();
            });
        }
});}
```