# How to logout only my FBapplication not my facebook account?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook javascript sdk on my web application. I am using graph api to login my application. When I logged out from my application, my application is logged out and my facebook account is also logout.

How to logout only my application not my facebook account ?

Please help me if someone has found solution for this.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

    var button;
    var userInfo;

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: '########', 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true});

       showLoader(true);

       function updateButton(response) {
            button       =   document.getElementById('fb-auth');
            userInfo     =   document.getElementById('user-info');
            userdata =   document.getElementById('user-data');
            if (response.authResponse) {
                //user is already logged in and connected
                FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                    login(response, info);
                });

                button.onclick = function() {
                    FB.logout(function(response) {
                        logout(response);
                    });
                };
            } else {
                //user is not connected to your app or logged out
                button.innerHTML = 'Login';
                button.onclick = function() {
                    showLoader(true);
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                                login(response, info);
                            });    
                        } else {
                            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                            showLoader(false);
                        }
                    },                                    {scope:'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'});   
                }
            }
        }

        // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
        FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);  
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol 
            + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());


    function login(response, info){
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var accessToken                                 =   response.authResponse.accessToken;

            userInfo.innerHTML                             = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + info.id + '/picture">' + info.name
                                                             + "<br /> Your Access Token: " + accessToken;


    button.innerHTML                               = 'Logout';
            showLoader(false);
            document.getElementById('other').style.display = "block";

        }
    }

    function logout(response){
        userInfo.innerHTML                             =   "";
        document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML     =   "";
        document.getElementById('other').style.display =   "none";
        showLoader(false);
    }

     //stream publish method
     function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){
        showLoader(true);
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'stream.publish',
            message: '',
            attachment: {
                name: name,
                caption: '',
                description: (description),
                href: hrefLink
            },
            action_links: [
                { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
            ],
            user_prompt_message: userPrompt
        },
        function(response) {
            showLoader(false);
        });

    }
    function showStream(){
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            //console.log(response.id);
            streamPublish();
        });
    }           

  function share(){
        showLoader(true);
        var share = {
            method: 'stream.share',
            u: 'http://www.appovative.com/'
        };

        FB.ui(share, function(response) { 
            showLoader(false);
            console.log(response); 
        });
    }



    function setStatus(){
        showLoader(true);

        status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;
        FB.api(
          {
            method: 'status.set',
            status: status1
          },
          function(response) {
            if (response == 0){
                alert('Your facebook status not updated. Give Status Update        Permission.');
            }
            else{
                alert('Your facebook status updated');
            }
            showLoader(false);
          }
        );
    }

    function showLoader(status){
        if (status)
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is function defined in FB object use this to destroy FB session ,

usage( via PHP)

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

**Or**

FB  API provides a logoutURL which will log the user out of their current Facebook account.

you can use it like this ,

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$params = array('next' => 'www.yousite.com/test.php' );
$logoutURL = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
```

***note
advisable to add below codes also (not in case if you dont want your user to log out of your site)

```
//remove PHPSESSID from browser
if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
    setcookie( session_name(), '', time()-7000000, '/' );
//clear session from globals
    $_SESSION = array();
```

With JS using a custom event
ref : ([FB.logout() called without an access token. javascript sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842610/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token-javascript-sdk))

```
function fbLogoutUser() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                document.location.reload();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am use the fbLogoutUser() function, this time also it logout my Facebook account.give any more suggestion plz..

Comment: else use php destroySession()

Comment: where I use the php destroySession() ?

Comment: in php code , while logout link click redirect to a page where you will call destroySession() method from FB object