# How to properly use FB.logout/getLoginStatus

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a webpage where when the user logins in, I execute [`FB.login`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.9):

```
FB.login(
  (response) => {
    if (response && response.authResponse) {
      console.log(response.authResponse);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Login failed');
    }
  },
  { scope: 'permissions,that,I,ask,for' }
);
```

Running that code, I successfully get back an authResponse with `status: "connected"`. I don't save the tokens in the response in any way.

When the user goes to logout, I call [`FB.logout`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/v2.9):

```
FB.logout((response) => console.log('Logged out', response));
```

This gives me the error `FB.logout() called without an access token`. Now, there are many SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430474/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842610/fb-logout-called-without-an-access-token-javascript-sdk/) for example) and blog posts that deal with how to handle that error. Specifically, most of them recommend wrapping your logout call in a [`FB.getLoginStatus`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/v2.9) call, the idea being that the FB SDK needs to have an internal copy of the access token.

```
FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
  if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.logout((logoutResponse) => console.log('Logged out, logoutResponse));
  }
});
```

However, when I do that, the response coming back from `FB.getLoginStatus` has `status: "unknown"`.

How can the status be unknown when 1) I just called `FB.login`, and then 2), I literally just called `FB.getLoginStatus`?

What do I need to do to get `FB.logout` to work properly?

(Tested in a Chrome 66 Incognito tab with no script blockers of any kind running.)

Here is the [`FB.init`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.9) call we use:

```
FB.init({
  appId: env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  version: 'v2.9',
});
```

If it's helpful: we wrap all async `FB.*` API calls with a Promise so that we can chain off of when they finish. For example:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  FB.login((response) => {
    if (response && response.authResponse) {
      resolve(response);
    } else {
      reject(new Error('FB.Login failed'));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you are calling login an then once again checking the status you get unkown? Can you provide a bit more code, to see how you call this methods and how FB ist loaded?

Comment: Show the SDK initialization settings, and check out the second parameter for getLoginStatus.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I get "unknown" as the status string back. What additional code do you want? The above is a simplified example yes, but the application as a whole has tens of thousands of lines of code.

Comment: @CBroe what SDK settings in particular are you thinking of? We put the `<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>` tag in the body of our page. I'll add the `FB.init` call to the end of the post now. I also tried passing `true` for the second param of `getLoginStatus` and it didn't change anything unfortunately :(

Comment: Yeah, I meant what parameters like `status` and `cookie` were set to. But `cookie` should only be relevant if you have a server-side component that needs to share the Facebook session, and if `status` is set to false, then getLoginStatus when explicitly instructed to check should fix that as well. What happens if you try a simple API call instead of calling FB.logout in that same place? If you had no valid token, that should fail as well?

Comment: @CBroe yeah, this is client-side only, so we aren't using any cookies. It's very interesting. If I call `FB.login()` immediately before (not wrapping, but before) the call to `FB.logout`, on the `FB.logout` call I get the error: `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` But I'm not trying to open any frames, so not sure why it would say that.

Comment: Are you on localhost?

Comment: @Michael yes, I'm running the server locally

Comment: In your case I would try it without wrapping it in Promises. Try to test it as essential as possible. Recheck also your FB dev App Settings on Facebook.